# My JavaScript code is not working in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is basic javascript program taken from w3schools.com.The following program has to return the 11(5+6).But it is only returning My First Webpage and my first paragraph.

Comment: Save this code properly and open the `html` file in browser. It must work

Comment: i am using Mozilla but it is not working.Everything is alright

Comment: It works well in Mozilla as well. I tried just now. Check if javascript is enabled in mozilla.

Comment: `not working in visual studio code` ...it's not intended to be "launched" in VS Code, it's just a text editor. Drag the HTML file in a browser.

Comment: Check my solution answer @KoushikReddy.  you may understand where you did mistakes!

Comment: just like @AKA, I put this code in a HTML file, dragged it in chrome and saw `My First Web Page, My First Paragraph, 11`. This works, there is just no reason why it wouldn't except if JS is disabled in the browser.

Comment: @JeremyThille i opened the html file in mozilla but no response

Comment: Well, try in Chrome then.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is working perfectly, take a look at the output below. May be you haven't saved the changes correctly.